# How I can add frequency for my timeseries DataFrame using asfreq("D") SUN-THU WEEK?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, frequency, forecasting

df.head(10)

```
    Close   year    month   day
Date                
2014-12-31  31.4816     2014    12  31
2015-01-04  31.6416     2015    1   4
2015-01-05  31.8336     2015    1   5
2015-01-06  31.1168     2015    1   6
2015-01-08  31.7440     2015    1   8
2015-01-11  31.6736     2015    1   11
2015-01-12  32.4032     2015    1   12
2015-01-13  32.7744     2015    1   13
2015-01-14  33.9008     2015    1   14
2015-01-15  33.5936     2015    1   15

freq=None
```

So I want to add frequency to my data to make seasonal decomposition

```
result = seasonal_decompose(df['Return'], model='add')
```

However using `asfreq('D')` for business day MON-FRI week and my Data is SUN-THU Week

So I want to know what frequency I can use or how I can adjust 'D' frequency to SUN-THU Week

Answer (score 0):

Using this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-find-day-of-the-week-for-a-given-date/ you can find the day for each column

```
# Python program to find the day of  
# the week for a given date 
import datetime 
import calendar 

def findDay(date): 
    born = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%d %m %Y').weekday() 
    return (calendar.day_name[born]) 

# Driver program 
df['day'] = findDay(df['Date'])
```

after that you could apply pandas `value_counts()` and find the frequency for every day.

`df.day.value_counts()`

Hope it answers your question.

Comment: Thanks AMal for your answer, but this is not what i am asking for.